# Select Or Insert Data In Table Using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to pull one record at a time from a result set to use as value in Select Statement for Inserting data in Table.

```
select [Id] 
from TBL 
where PId = '123' 
order by value
```

Result-set1

```
222
333
444
555
```

Query #2:

```
select [Id] 
from TBL 
where PId = '456' 
order by value
```

Result-set2

```
666
777
888
999
```

Finally I am trying to insert data into a table by taking value from `Result-set1` and `Result-set2`.

```
insert into TBL ([Val], [Disp], [Seq], [Active], [DId], [PId])
    select [Val], [Disp], [Seq], [Active], 'One Record From Result-set1', '1111' 
    from TBL 
    where PId = '2222' 
      and DId = 'One Record From Result-set2'
```

I read that cursor helps to pull one record at a time from a result set but I am not sure how to implement it in my scenario.

```
insert into TBL ([Val], [Disp], [Seq], [Active], [DId], [PId])
    select [Val], [Disp], [Seq], [Active], '222', '1111' 
    from TBL 
    where PId = '2222' 
      and DId = '666'
```

I am trying to get rid of hard coding 222 and 666.

Comment: It's very difficult to read your question in the way you have written it.

Comment: I am really sorry could you please suggest me edits I will surely correct it. Not sure but in preview it was looking perfect.

Comment: Why do you want to insert one record at a time? Thats not really how SQL Server is intended, you can insert multiple in one go?

Comment: @Dale: Actually based on the “DId” I am pulling multiple records from same table and inserting the value for one of “PId”

Comment: @Aaron: Yeah it was by mistake. I will remove that.

Comment: @Omi sure but why not do the entire insert in one go? What is the reason for splitting it up?

Comment: @Dale: Yeah I want to perform entire Insert at a one go. But currently I need to replace “DId” eveytime because each “DId” of result set 2 is having bulk records. Hope that is clear. I am looking for a way to pull one by one “DId” from my result set 1 and 2 and I will use this in a stored procedure to execute the Insert statement at one go.

Comment: Doing this in a cursor to insert one row at a time is going to do nothing but be a slow and more difficult to maintain approach to what should be a simple insert statement.

Comment: If you explain the logic for how you are replacing "DId" we would then be able to assist in creating a single insert statement, or at least determine whether its possible.

Comment: @Sean: Could you please suggest me how can I adjust my query to pull one value at a time from my result set 1 and result set 2 and replace in the Insert statement?

Comment: @Dale: “DId” I am getting by executing select statement where “PId” is 123 and 456. Instead of hard coding the value of “DId” I want to establish a way where the insert statement can be written inside a loop and executed. For reference please see the edit in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both of your queries return the same number of records (which is a big assumption) you can join both datasets using an Id created with row number.
Then, you can use a cartesian product to insert as many records in your table as results returned by your query.

```
insert into TBL ([Val], [Disp], [Seq], [Active], [DId], [PId])
select [Val], [Disp], [Seq], [Active], cj.Id1, '1111' 
from TBL 
  cross join (
    select rs1.[Id] Id1, rs2.[Id] Id2
    from (    
      select 
        row_number() over (partition by (select null) order by value) rn,
        [Id] 
      from TBL where PId = '123'
    ) rs1
    join (
      select 
        row_number() over (partition by (select null) order by value) rn,
        [Id] 
      from TBL where PId = '456'
    ) rs2
  on rs1.rn=rs2.rn
  ) cj
where PId = '2222' 
  and DId = cj.Id2
```

Comment: Yes Jaime, my select statements where PId=123 and PId=456 gives me same number of rows and data is also same only the Id/DId is different.

Comment: Ok, then check that query. With your requirements, this must work. A cursor is not explicitly needed for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Jaime let me try.